# Laravel 5.4 put method strange behavior

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my Routes:

```
/*
 * Photos route group
 */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/photos', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'PhotoController@edit')->name('photos.edit');

    Route::get('/new', 'PhotoController@create')->name('photos.new');

    Route::get('/', 'PhotoController@index')->name('photos.show');

    Route::post('/', 'PhotoController@store')->name('photos.save');

    Route::put('/update/{id}', 'PhotoController@update')->name('photos.update');

});
```

And this is my update method in photo model:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Photo $photo, $id)
    {
        //return [$request->all(), $photo::all()];
        return $id;
    }
```

And finally this is where my form will be created

```
            <form action="{{ route('photos.update', ['id' => $photo->id]) }}">
                {{ method_field('put') }}
                {{ csrf_field() }}
```

**BUT** when I use this configuration, laravel return `methodNotAllowedException`. when I change `put` method to `post`, again this will return same result, But when I change method to `get` the page will work fine.

I did reorder my routes in `web.php` file but the problem exists again.

Do you know what is wrong in my code?

**NOTE :**

I have some other update methods in other models and these are OK, This problem occurs just for this model...

***`Thanks in Advance`***

Comment: add `method="post"` to your form

Answer (score 0):

Try always simple

roures.php

```
 Route::post('/photos/update', 'PhotoController@update');
```

view.blade.php

```
    <form action="/photos/update" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
```

Controller.php

```
public function update(Request $request)    {
        //return [$request->all(), $photo::all()];
        return redirect('home');
    }
```

Comment: @Hasan Tingir we can use put and post medthod

Comment: but as I know we should use 'put' method when we update our data ?

Comment: Well thanks for your reply but I did test @Andriy Lozinskiy And your suggestion and there's everything as the same

Comment: @HasanTıngır When your edit deviates from an existing answer, please add an answer with your proposed solution.